# Sequelize: how to import definitions from an existing database

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Am I required to handwrite the model definitions for Sequelize even if I'm working off of an existing database.

If it's not required, then how does one go about using Sequelize with an existing database?

I've already defined the database's schema in Doctrine, so I'd rather not have to write another set of model definitions again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

with Sequelize you have to define the structure of the model inside your code. Doing so, Sequelize assumes a specific database schema unless something is overwritten. So in short: No, sequelize cannot mirror the database.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. If I find the time I might try to add a module to this project to export the schema from a MySQL Workbench file, since that's the point of origin for most of my projects.

https://github.com/johmue/mysql-workbench-schema-exporter

Answer (score 121):

This project aims to create Sequelize models from existing schema https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto

### Sequelize-Auto

A tool to automatically generate models for `SequelizeJS` via the command line.

### Install:

```
npm install -g sequelize-auto
```

### Usage:

```
sequelize-auto -h <host> -d <database> -u <user> -x [password] -p [port]  --dialect [dialect] -c [/path/to/config] -o [/path/to/models]
```

### Options:

```
  -h, --host      IP/Hostname for the database.                                      [required]
  -d, --database  Database name.                                                     [required]
  -u, --user      Username for database.                                             [required]
  -x, --pass      Password for database.
  -p, --port      Port number for database.
  -c, --config    JSON file for sending additional options to the Sequelize object.
  -o, --output    What directory to place the models.
  -e, --dialect   The dialect/engine that you're using: postgres, mysql, sqlite
```

**Example**

```
sequelize-auto -o "./models" -d sequelize_auto_test -h localhost -u daniel -p 5432 -x my_password -e postgres
```

Produces a file/files such as **`./models/Users.js`** which looks like this:

```
/* jshint indent: 2 */

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('Users', {
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: null
    },
    touchedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: null
    },
    aNumber: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: null
    },
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: null
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: null
    }
  });
};
```

Which makes it easy for you to simply **`Sequelize.import`** it.

Comment: One major note about sequelize-auto project: it **DID NOT** support importing **associations** YET (as of May 2016). So, you should define them "manually", in code. 

But definitely its much easier when you have basic database structure already imported!

Comment: @deksden how to add the assosiations

Comment: @Jegan : here is dedicated article in documentation - http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/associations/