# Creating Sequelize Models

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm researching Sequelize for use in a project with an existing data-filled database.  I like the way it works, but I'm trying to figure out if I have to write the models by hand.  Entity Framework and other ORMs have features that will generate code models for you, using the database schema as a starting point.  It looks like Sequelize hasn't gotten there, but I want to be sure I'm not missing something.

TL;DR:
**Do I need to write my Sequelize models by hand for an existing database, or is there a way to generate them?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sequelize: how to import definitions from an existing database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060265/sequelize-how-to-import-definitions-from-an-existing-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [sequelize-auto](https://www.npmjs.org/package/sequelize-auto) package will create Sequelize definitions from an existing database.